# How to avoid terminal to scroll down to last message in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, bash-scripting, gnome-terminal

I write a bash script that run some other commands in new terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Sample script
gnome-terminal --title="blah blah" -x bash -c ffmpeg -i udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000000 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -preset ultrafast \
-flags -global_header -f hls -hls_time 20 -hls_wrap 5 /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8 &

sleep 1

gnome-terminal --title="blah blah" -x bash -c ffmpeg -i udp://239.1.2.2:60002?fifo_size=50000000 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -preset ultrafast \
-flags -global_header -f hls -hls_time 20 -hls_wrap 5 /var/www/html/ts/2.m3u8
```

The output of each `ffmpeg` line is more than one page and it is similar to:

```
libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101

  ... many pages after ....

[h264 @ 0xc04c60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0xc04c60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0xc04c60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced

.... many pages after .... 

  Program 105 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : IRIB-TV5
      service_provider: IRIB
[adts @ 0xf943e0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
Output #0, hls, to '/home/stream/Desktop/tst/1.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1(per): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac_latm (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0xf42120] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0xf42120] Missing reference picture, default is 65716
[h264 @ 0xf42120] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0xf42120] Missing reference picture, default is 65717
```

When I run this script in a new terminal and I launch the command (in this case `ffmpeg`), it immediately shows many output lines, many pages sometimes,   and **goes to last message automatically**...

How can I scroll up and down to first message in the terminal, or stop it at the  first page?

Comment: Ok now this is another question. Use `| more ` or `| less` to stop the output after the first page (then you need to press enter...  Example `gnome-terminal --title="blah blah" -x bash -c  ' find  ~  | less'`

Comment: and what i must do for go to last page?

Comment: See below the update answer or search on your computer with `man less` or `man more`.

Comment: Perfect...tnx a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I tried to make more clear your text. Feel you free to [edit] again or to _"rollback"_ the modifications. Btw the first message is the more hidden in the terminal (more up), not the last one: for this it was difficult to understand you... :-) ps> Welcome on SuperUser.

Comment: tnx agin...one problem with run more than 1 command in another terminal is that output log lock on first page(without use `| less` ) .. i think its refer to terminal that lunch command more fast....do you have idea for solve that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update after that the question was completely reformulated:*

You can use `| more` or `| less` to stop the output after the first page.

```
 gnome-terminal --title="blah blah" -x bash -c  ' find  ~  | less'
```

**Note**: you need to use `''` to say where it finishes the bash commands.
Within `less` you can move:

- <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> To the beginning and the end of the page.
- <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> One page down or up.
- <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Dn</kbd> One line up or down.

---

One of the line of your script can be similar to

```
gnome-terminal --title="blah blah" -x bash -c                                 \
'ffmpeg -i udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000000 -acodec copy -vcodec copy \
-preset ultrafast -flags -global_header -f hls -hls_time 20 -hls_wrap 5       \
/var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8 | less ' &
```

---

There are some shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Dn</kbd> To scroll up or down of a line
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>or <kbd>PgDn</kbd> To scroll up or down of a page
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> To scroll up to the beginning or down to the end

You can read about other shortcuts directly on the [gnome help page](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en).

Comment: But i want to do that in bash , for example in the end of my coomand...is it possible?

Comment: I misunderstood it (nice version of you may be more clear `;-)` ): add a `| less` or `| more` to your command. Example `tree . | less`. BTW this redirect the stdout.  If you want to redirect even the stderr you have to write explicitly. (Example `tree .  2>&1 | less `). Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I use dvblast (a program for live tv streaming) ...i start dvblast 10 times for 10 channels...when i start dvblast it show many massages in terminal and i want to see last message ...i run dvblast with the code that i said in question and i want to do that in that code

Comment: @combo_ci My _dear_ it is the 3rd time you change your question... now you are asking a different question (and a specific one). Take some moment to read [ask]. It will help you to have the answer you need and the others to avoid to waste time answering to an unneeded question. Nothing personal. BTW do another question adding a typical output, the desired output and the information if you run all the 10 `dvblast` from the same shell...

Comment: Tnx for reply but i think my question is clear ... I run terminam from bash...output of terminal is too line that not show in one pge....i want to force terminal to scoll down to last message ...just it

Comment: @combo_ci The terminal usually _"scrolls down"_ to the last line of the output, if the output exceeds the number of lines of the screen the previous messages go _up_. If there are too many line (over the buffer size) you progressively go to loose the older one. As you said it seems (you didn't specify yet) your ran all 10 `dvblast` in the same terminal: this will mix their outputs...  Try to open a gnome-terminal and to write `find ~`. Check if it scrolls correctly.

Comment: its better to change my question :) ...i etided question...forget dvblast...i write script with ffmpeg....in fact application is not important...the important isuee is i want to scroll to last message (or first message ) in terminal by write some code in my script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37473/discussion-between-hastur-and-combo-ci).